# How to run .ktr transformations in PHP

Tags: php, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I developed the following API in PHP / HTML:

[image]

I need the result of the select option to serve input to the following ETL transformation:

[image]

[image]

I used "RJ" as an example in the query. But I need this result to come from the API. What step can I use to recover this data?
Is the reverse process possible? Can I make the result of this transformation available (which is an excel worksheet) for the user to download?

Edit 1: That's how I get the form results. It's a simple PHP code.

```
<?php
            $conexaobd = new ConexaoBD;
            $conexao = $conexaobd->conectarAoBD();
            $buscar=$_POST['buscar'];
            $sql = "SELECT p.id_projeto, p.municipio, p.estado, p.nome FROM projeto p WHERE p.estado LIKE '%".$buscar."%' ORDER BY p.id_projeto";
                        $resultado_query = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
            if (!$resultado_query) {
                echo "Erro: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conexao);
            }
            if (!$linha = $resultado_query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                echo "<h3>Nenhum registro encontrado.</h3>";
            } else {
                while($linha = $resultado_query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                    $id = $linha['id_projeto'];
                    $municipio = $linha['municipio'];
                    $estado = $linha['estado'];
                    $nome = $linha['nome'];
                    echo "<h2><strong>ID do projeto: </strong>".@$id."</h2>";
                    echo "<br/>";
                    echo "<strong>Município: </strong>".@$municipio;
                    echo "<br/>";
                    echo "<strong>Estado: </strong>".@$estado;
                    echo "<br/>";
                    echo "<strong>Nome do projeto: </strong>".@$nome;
                    echo "<br/>";

                }
            }

        ?>
```

Comment: How do you get these results from the API ?
How does the API responds ? Is it a REST Client that accepts POST/GET Metohds, what does it return ? A JSON ? An XML ?

Comment: I edited the post with php code.

Comment: The way i know how to do this is either by using the HTTP POST or the REST Client steps in PDI, to get the result, this being the PHP code, do you have a URL you use to achieve the same result ?

Comment: Actually, it's stored on my localhost. I only have page path. Like this: http://localhost/consultas-opensoils/visao/buscar_estado.php